# Multiple nested if blocks in google spreadsheets formulas

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

Im trying to write a nested if statement like this pseudo code :

```
=IF(h4=1, "CORRECT", IF(h4=2, "CORRECT"), IF(h4=3, "CORRECT"), IF(h4=4, "CORRECT"))
```

But im getting the following error, if i write out the code about and add an if statement each time. ie. start with only the first if block and then add more testing each time, it breaks when i add the third statement.

> Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments,
>   but received 4 arguments.

Is there a better way to nest if blocks in google spreadsheets ?

Ive made a google spreadsheet of the issue here : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MBOmaTNI5C_spSVudCQPeanHtoFr36kglg9BXUeAZxU/edit#gid=0

(the above code is only an example of nesting IF blocks, not the actual issue im trying to solve)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error was actually just a simple syntax issue - the placement of your parentheses - here is the correct:

```
=IF(H4=1, "CORRECT", IF(H4=2, "CORRECT", IF(H4=3, "CORRECT")))
```

I also fixed it on your spreadsheet.

Every if statement must have 3 parts essentially, so if(this, then this, else this) so when nesting, the else this part of the formula is the next condition..

```
=IF(h4=1, "CORRECT", IF(h4=2, "CORRECT", IF(h4=3, "CORRECT", IF(h4=4, "CORRECT"))))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Short answer

Instead of nesting multiple IFs, try to use a formula that doesn't require that. Considering the example provided, one alternative is the following:

```
=IF(AND(h1>=1,h4<=4),"CORRECT")
```

## Explanation

If it's possible, avoid function nesting as it could make a formula harder to read and debug.