# Multiple Nested IF Statement

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm struggling with the correct syntax for a nested IF statement in Google Sheets. My current formula, evaluates the date values in cell N10 and O10 against the dates defined in BA9. If true, it enters LIVE into the cell. However, I need to be able to evaluate against other cells too. For example, I'd have additional dates that are in AU10 and AV10 that need also need to checked.

```
=IF(AND(BA$9>=($N10-(WEEKDAY($N10,2)-1)),BA$9<=($O10-(WEEKDAY($O10,2)-1)+6)),"LIVE","N/A")
```

Comment: Hello Ryan! from your current post it's hard to guess what is your final destination, and what is it exactly that you want to achieve. The amount of cells you wish to compare, for example - is it finite? I mean is it just those 4 cells you mentioned or it should be scalable? Is the comparison with each of those cells different or the same?

Comment: Hi @Barackos, it is a finite amount and the cells would be defined in the formula.

Comment: @Ryan Welcome. Your problem isn't clear. The `IF` compares BA$9, $N10, and $O10. You refer to AU10 and AV10 but you don't explain how they are to be checked. Do you really want a nested IF, or do you want to extend the existing `AND` statement, or maybe both. Please edit your question to describe the logic of how the additional dates are to be checked, and how they relate to the existing formula. [Multiple nested if blocks in google spreadsheets formulas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164826/) is a very good example of using 'nested ifs' and/or AND statements. I suggest you read it.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(AND(AND(BA$9 >=($N10-(WEEKDAY($N10, 2)-1)),
            BA$9 <=($O10-(WEEKDAY($O10, 2)-1)+6)),
        AND(AU$10>=($N10-(WEEKDAY($N10, 2)-1)),
            AU$10<=($O10-(WEEKDAY($O10, 2)-1)+6)),
        AND(AV$10>=($N10-(WEEKDAY($N10, 2)-1)),
            AV$10<=($O10-(WEEKDAY($O10, 2)-1)+6))), "LIVE", "N/A")
```

[image]